# how to determine which parameter at fault when "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When searching here on stackoverflow, it's apparent that System.ArgumentException "Value does not fall within the expected range" occurs in many different API calls for many different reasons. I'm seeking general advice for determining WHICH specific parameter, in an API call that has a lot of parameters, is the root cause. Perhaps the exception itself contains that info somewhere, or a debugger feature that will clarify it? The particular example I've encountered is in VS2017 "Community", at this call:

```
var bmp = BitmapSource.Create(img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight, DPI, DPI, PixelFormats.Rgb24, img.Palette, destPixelData, img.PixelWidth/24);
```

Comment: Look at the properties the `System.ArgumentException` class provides...

Comment: In this particular case, logical analysis led me to realize that the last parameter was the root cause (changing "/ 24" to "* 3" fixed it), but the general question is still open (for me)

Comment: There's no general solution to this. The Create function should be creating the ArgumentException using the constructor that accepts both a message and the parameter name, at which point its ToString() operator behaves differently and shows you what it is. The fact that you're only seeing a message, and the parameter property isn't set internally, says that the code doesn't do this and effectively throws that information away...which is unusual because if you look at the source code you'll see that most of the time they do do it properly. Not very helpful, I know, but it is what it is.

Comment: @elgonzo HAS provided the answer I sought (the System.ArgumentException.ParamName property is what I was looking for -- it is available in the "View Details" dialog). I tried to post an answer to my question, but it's held for moderation, or something went wrong somewhere.